# etree: Element.iter() wrapper that holds the current path and the current element

Tags: python, iterator, elementtree

As for `list`s, that can be wrapped with `enumerate()` to provide the index **and** the current element, I would love to have a wrapper for `.iter()`:

```
for path,element in iter_wrapper(xmltree.iter()):
    pass
```

Where the `path` is a list of all parent elements.
For illustration, the very very inefficient way would be to do

```
path = []
it = element.getparent()
while it is not None:
    path += [it]
    it.getparent()
```

in every iteration of `.iter()`, but obviously there is a dynamic way.
How can I access the current path of `.iter()`, since internally the iterator knows 'where it currently is in the tree'?

Comment: What exactly is your question? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way do access the internal properties of the iterator. Thus, the only way left was implementing a new iterator:

```
def iterate_etree(elem, parents=set()):
    yield (parents, elem)

    parents |= set([elem])

    for gen in elem:
        for child in iterate_etree(gen, parents):
            yield child

    parents -= set([elem])
```

which can be called like so:

```
from lxml import etree
xmltree = etree.parse(some_xml_file)

for parents, element in iterate_etree(xmltree):
    pass
```